# Python threads remaining active after socket client disconnect

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up a client/server using sockets in Python between a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian and my PC running Windows 10. My server script counts the number of active threads each time a client connects. When I connect and disconnect with my client script, the active thread count keeps increasing. I looked online, and found that it's generally bad practice to kill an active thread. If I keep increasing the active thread count by repeatedly connecting and disconnecting my Raspberry pi client with my PC server, will this eat up processing time? Is there a clean way to terminate an active thread? You can see the client and server programs I am using for testing below:

server.py

```
import socket
import threading
import multiprocessing
from commands import run_command
import time

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
SERVER = [IP Address]
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"


def handle_client(conn, addr):

    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected")

    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                connect = False
                print("disconnected")
            print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
            run_command(msg)
        time.sleep(0.001)
    conn.close()


def start():
    print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        # thread = multiprocessing.Process(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        # print(multiprocessing.active_children)
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server.bind(ADDR)
    start()
```

client.py

```
import socket

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
SERVER = [IP Address]
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

class ServerClient():

    def __init__(self):
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.client.settimeout(.5)
        try:
            self.client.connect(ADDR)
            print("Connected to server")
        except (socket.timeout, BlockingIOError) as e:
            print("Could not connect to server")

    def send_message(self, msg):
        try:
            message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
            msg_length = len(message)
            send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
            send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
            self.client.send(send_length)
            self.client.send(message)
            print(f"Message sent to server: {msg}")
        except (socket.timeout, TimeoutError) as e :
            print("could not send message to server")
    
    def disconnect(self):
        try:
            self.send_message(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
            self.client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
            self.client.close()
            print("Disconnected from server")
        except socket.timeout:
            print("Could not disconnect from server")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = ServerClient()
    sc.send_message("lol")
    sc.disconnect()
```

As you can see above, I've already tried using:
`self.client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`
This did not seem to solve the problem (if there is one).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks generally fine. Just two minor observations:

```
connected = True
while connected:
    msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
    if msg_length:
        msg_length = int(msg_length)
        msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
        if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
            connect = False     # Wrong variable used here
            print("disconnected")
        print(f"[{addr}] {msg}")
        run_command(msg)
    time.sleep(0.001)
conn.close()
```

In this part you set `connect = False` instead of `connected = False`, which means your while loop never breaks. Fixing that might solve your problem alone.

As your code is written now you will also execute `run_command()` once after receiving disconnect. If this is intentional, then all good. If you don't want to do that, add `continue` to your conditional to exit the loop immediately.

Your code probably does not recover from a client error or broken connection, though.  Your server would just enter a busyloop if the server breaks the connection, but this I leave for you to fix.

You could actually solve both problems by getting rid of the connected variable completely. Just make it a `while True` loop and `break` either at disconnect or any socket error.

Comment: Yup- that's exactly what the problem was. Thank you for thorough reply- your other suggestions were very helpful as well.